# Spring data elasticsearch wrong page totalPages

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a simple repository

```java
@Repository
public interface SurgeryIndexRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<SurgeryIndexEntity, UUID> {}
```

When I call the `search` method like this `surgeryIndexRepository.search(query, pageable)` I get a Page response with `totalPages = 1`, `numberOfElements=40`, `totalElements=7200`.
Something is wrong with the `totalPages`, I should have `180`.

My `Pageable` is `Page request [number: 0, size 40, sort: date: DESC]`

I'm using `Maven: org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.6.RELEASE`

Comment: Looks like other people also have the [same issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/170#issuecomment-330412336)

Comment: Yep and just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896753/elasticsearch-return-totalpages-not-correct leading to this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-402
I'm gonna try it now ;)

Comment: Good find, let us know how it goes!

Comment: just posted an anwser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has been resolved in `3.0.7` : https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-402, we were using `3.0.6`, so just upgraded to current release version `3.0.8.RELEASE` and it solved the problem.

Another reference to this problem : [elasticsearch: return TotalPages not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896753/elasticsearch-return-totalpages-not-correct)